# How can I print a webpage section that has been styled using tailwind css

Tags: javascript, tailwind-css

I have a webpage section that contains a report that needs to be printed. The report  is lengthy, and has been styled using tailwindcss. Below is my tailwind.config file, and the method to print the section. Kindly help, thanks in advance.

```js
// Tailwind Config file
module.exports = {
  content: ["./index.html",
    "./src/**/*.{vue,js,ts,jsx,tsx}",
  ],
  theme: {
    extend: {
      screens: {
        print: {
          raw: 'print'
        },
        screen: {
          raw: 'screen'
        }
      }
    },
  },
  plugins: [],
}

// Function to Print

printReport() {
  let prtContent = document.getElementById("report");
  let WinPrint = window.open('', '', 'left=0,top=0,width=800,height=900,toolbar=0,scrollbars=0,status=0');
  WinPrint.document.write(prtContent.innerHTML);
  WinPrint.document.close();
  WinPrint.focus();
  WinPrint.print();
  WinPrint.close();

},
```

Comment: So you have some code there and I'm guessing it's not working. I advise you test the code just in  a pure HTML+CSS+JS context, without tailwinds or builds or anything. Do you get any errors or log output at all? Also, imagine if websites could trigger a print for its users - that would be _very_ bad and generally is blocked by security features - it might be allowed under certain special conditions though - in any case, the first step is to see log output